# get combinations of 2 from a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, combinations

I need to get combinations of 2 from a string in javascript

```
var string = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
```

Expected output

```
aa
ab
ac
...
```

I have found this but I cannot figure out how to filter only 2-length combinations, and avoid other "extra" calculations:

```
var string = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';

var tree = function(leafs){
    var branches = [];      
    if(leafs.length == 1) return leafs;       
    for(var k in leafs){
        var leaf = leafs[k];
        tree(leafs.join('').replace(leaf,'').split('')).concat("").map(function(subtree){
            branches.push([leaf].concat(subtree));
        });
    }
    return branches;
};
console.log(tree(string.split('')).map(function(str){return str.join('')}))
```

Comment: why the downvotes?

Comment: I haven't voted down but i guess it's because you're not showing your tries

Comment: I was just preparing it better I am tryiung to do it fast, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var string = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
var combinations = []

for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    for (var j = i; j < string.length; j++) {
        combinations.push(string[i] + string[j])
    }
}
```

This will produce `aa, ab... bb, bc... zz`. If you want `aa, ab... ba, bb... zz`, just change the second for loop to `for (var j = 0...`

Comment: Thank you so much! You made my day

Answer (score 1):

In order to make combinations of 2 over the same string you could iterate over it as follows

```
var string = "abcdefghijklmnoprstuvwxyz";
for (var i = 0; i < string.length; ++i )
{
    for (var j = 0; j < string.length; ++j)
    {
        console.log(string[i]+string[j]);
    }
}
```

I have printed the result out but you could easily store it as well